# Printing a dictionary based on the size of the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
`{'a':2,'b':3,'c':2}`
```

I need to print the keys and values starting with the biggest value. Desired output below:

```
'b' 3
'a' 2
'c' 2
```

The order of 'a' and 'c' does not necessarily have to be alphabetical, the important thing is that the **largest value is printed first** and so on.

I'm writing in python 3.

I have tried to create a new dictionary using the old values as keys and vice versa, but the issue was that I had the same values several times.

Can someone help a confused student solve this question?

Comment: This is the first time i post so it got really ugly... the result im looking for is 'b'    3  on the first line and then 'a'   2 on the next     and 'c'    2  on the last

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Please *always use the generic [python]* tag for python questions

Answer (score 0):

By `iteritems` method convert the object into a list, sort it (here with help of `sortSec` custom function), and then print in a loop:

```
def sort_sec(val): 
    return val[1]  

input = {'a':2,'b':3,'c':2}
dictlist = []

for key, value in input.iteritems():
    dictlist.append([key,value])

dictlist.sort(key=sort_sec, reverse=True)

for el in dictlist:
    print(el[0] + ' ' + str(el[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, here's a simple solution:

```
dd = {'a':2,'b':3,'c':2}
ll = (zip(dd.values(), dd.keys()))
ll.sort(reverse=True) # Sorted by value
[(3, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'a')] # Print as needed
```